# how to display comments of single post?

Tags: wordpress, comments

I want to show comments of a post on single post page, but in that page I show the other post with same category too. when I use comments_template(); the comments of other post shown too. here is my code

```
<?php if(have_posts()): while(have_posts()): the_post();  ?>
   // show the single post and get the category of post
<?php endwhile;endif; ?>

if(isset($cats_arr) && !empty($cats_arr)){

        $args = array( 
                'category__in' => $cats_arr, 
                'posts_per_page'=>3,
                'post__not_in' => array( $post->ID ) );

        $the_query= new wp_query($args);

        if($the_query->have_posts()): while($the_query->have_posts()): 
        $the_query->the_post();  ?>

 //// shoe same category post title and image
 <?php endwhile;endif ?>

 <?php comments_template();  ?>
```

Can you help me find my problem?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add wp_reset_postdata(); to end of second query after if statment